# Rails paperclip and amazon S3 'PermanentRedirect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I try to use **paperclip** and Amazon s3. My bucket is in **EU** **(Ireland)** And I got this error :

```
AWS::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect in MyControllerController

The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

This is very annoying, I tried to fix this but I think I'm gonna die keep trying.

So this is my code :

```
s3.yml

access_key_id: *****
secret_access_key: ****
bucket: mybucketname
AWS_CALLING_FORMAT: s3-eu-west-1-amazonaws.com #not sure for this one
```

I've put the calling format 10 min ago for a last test, but nothing change

```
 config/initializers/paperclip.rb


Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-eu-west-1-amazonaws.com'
```

and so, my model :

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => "pictures/:id/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => 'mybucketname'
```

and finally

```
# in config/initializers/something.rb
 Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) { |assets, style|
 "#{assets.s3_protocol}://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{assets.recipesappdev}  /#{assets.path(style).gsub(%r{^/}, "")}"
   }
```

So, If I forgot to put a file here, don't hesitate to tell me.
Anybody has an idea ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Now I have this error :

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

... Really no idea

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't succeeded to fix this.
To avoid this problem, I use an US bucket, no EU

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set the `url: ":s3_domain_url"` as in this documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Here's my configuration. I'm not sure if you need all of it like the path or region:

`# development.rb
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    url: ":s3_domain_url",
    path: ":class/:id/:attachment/:style.:extension",
    s3_region: "us-east-2",
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: "whoops-proof-dev",
      access_key_id: "___",
      secret_access_key: "___",
    },
  }`